# Using jest to test async function that does not have callback

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, puppeteer

I'm currently looking to test an async function, a scraper that scrapes Ryan Air's website for a price on a given route to be exact. And I want to test that the scraped price is actually what the price should be. When trying to run it with jest to test, I cannot seem to make it work properly... I've looked on Google and various other sites and they all seem to have solutions for async functions that have callbacks, promises, etc. and NOT async functions that don't have those.

My function takes as a parameter the URL of a given route on Ryan Air.

Here is my async function (file is named scraperProduct.js):

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function scraperProduct(url){
    console.log('Starting scraper...');
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);
    await page.waitFor(500);

    //Price departure
    const [el1] = await page.$x('/html/body/flights-root/div/div/div/div/flights-summary-container/flights-summary/div/div[1]/journey-container/journey/div/div[2]/carousel-container/carousel/div/ul/li[3]/carousel-item/button/div[2]/ry-price/span[2]');
    const txt = await el1.getProperty('textContent');
    const Price = await txt.jsonValue();


    //Price return
    const [el6] = await page.$x('/html/body/flights-root/div/div/div/div/flights-summary-container/flights-summary/div/div[2]/journey-container/journey/div/div[2]/carousel-container/carousel/div/ul/li[3]/carousel-item/button/div[2]/ry-price/span[2]');
    const txt6 = await el6.getProperty('textContent');
    const Price2 = await txt6.jsonValue();

    return Price + Price2;
}

module.exports = scraperProduct;
```

And this is my test file (named scraperProduct.test.js):

```
const scraperProduct = require('./scraperProduct');

test("Testing that scraper retrieves correct price from Ryan Air", async () => {
    expect(
        scraperProduct('https://www.ryanair.com/dk/da/trip/flights/select?adults=1&teens=0&children=0&infants=0&dateOut=2020-07-13&dateIn=2020-07-20&originIata=CPH&destinationIata=STN&isConnectedFlight=false&isReturn=true&discount=0')
        ).toBe(698);
});
```

'toBe(698)' is 698 since that is what the price should be in the test.

I appreciate any help I can get with this - it's my first time using jest, so I'm a bit of a noob atm.

Comment: `expect(...).resolves.toBe(698)`? See https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-async, you *do* have promises (an `async` function *always* returns a promise). But note that unit tests shouldn't make network requests, and you should't rely on a value that could change over time.

Comment: Jonrsharpe, first of all, many thanks for that extremely fast response. I really appreciate that. Second of all, it worked. Third of all, I'm a Uni student (software engineering) and we are doing a whole project around this scraper, where we have built a website and a full program, where a user can start a ''job'' on whatever route they wish to, and then can see graphical data on how the price changes over the scraping period. For our project, it is a MUST to do unit-testing, and we, as a group, thought that testing that it actually manages to retrieve the correct price would be essential.

Comment: I think that's a good thing to test, I just wouldn't consider it *unit* testing. See e.g. https://twitter.com/techgirl1908/status/1174786419836874752. The problem with this one is the "correct" price can change over time, then your tests start failing *despite the code working*. I might consider an integration-level test that touches a real page and shows that a value that's plausibly a price can be retrieved, to ensure we see failures if e.g. the page layout changes, but only test specific values in a more controlled environment.

Comment: As explained, this is not unit but functional/integration/e2e/whatever you call it test. As for unit tests, you can mock puppeteer entirely, which may be a tough task, or mock only nondeterministic parts, i.e. network. Check teremock for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are trying to test an `async` function, you need to wait for the result of that function i.e use `await`.

This is one of the possible solutions when testing asynchronous code. Wait for the result and then test it.

```
const scraperProduct = require('./scraperProduct');

test("Testing that scraper retrieves correct price from Ryan Air", async () => {

    const result = await scraperProduct('https://www.ryanair.com/dk/da/trip/flights/select?adults=1&teens=0&children=0&infants=0&dateOut=2020-07-13&dateIn=2020-07-20&originIata=CPH&destinationIata=STN&isConnectedFlight=false&isReturn=true&discount=0')

    expect(result).toBe(698);
});
```